# jQuery script not loading?

Tags: jquery, html, css

https://jsfiddle.net/11632r3m/

I am trying to produce a simple colour change for a div element in my HTML file. It is not working for me, the fiddle attached is a sample of what doesn't work.

HTML

```
<div class="pagewrap"></div>
<div class="sidebar"></div> <!--Sidebar container-->   
<div class="mainbody"></div> <!--Main Body container-->
```

CSS

```
.sidebar {
    float: left;
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 10%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
```

}

jQuery

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".sidebar").click(function() {
        $(this).css("background-color","black");
    });
});
```

Comment: Press F12 and read the errors. Your code works -- you just neglected to include jQuery

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You needed to include end brackets and end divs for some of your code.

```
<div class="pagewrap"><!--Everything container-->
  <div class="sidebar"></div> <!--Sidebar container-->   
  <div class="mainbody"></div><!--Main Body container-->
</div>

.sidebar {
  float: left;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 10%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed; 
}
```

Secondly, you forgot to include JQuery as a library in your fiddle. So it couldn't find the variable.

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/11632r3m/7/

Comment: The updated fiddle works, but not on my IDE (Brackets).

Comment: Make sure jQuery is included in your script then.

Answer (score -1):

your codes is not work becouse **jquery library** in not loaded.
for that you can open fiddle and then on **javascript** section in the fiddle : 
select the javascript toggle and set the **FRAMEWORKS & EXTENSIONS** to jquery 3.2.1 and tadaaaaa !
your codes is working well